# Android java application slow when debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, debugging

when running application without debugger (JAVA ONLY) the app behaves as it should, meaning it is fast and crispy.

When i run the application in debug - java only debug (NO BREAKPOINTS) the app loads fragments very slow, for example custom keypad 13 buttons inflate takes 1 second, and when onResume is called and status of fragment is "visible" it still needs a second to actualy see the visible on screen.

Is my debugger faulty in some way or this is just the way it is ?
Can i speedup the debugging somehow?

With kind regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No your debugger is not faulty it takes time because it keep checking the origin of a functions and it helps us to debug properly. If you want to speed up your debugging than keep the code simple as possible or there is no way to speed up.
Thank you.

Comment: That is kind of sad but ok ... Java never was fast :D